# All time QB with the worst December+ INT ratio

Tags: american-football, statistics, nfl

For a long time I've been a fan of Matthew Stafford.  He had suffered in Detroit for years.  Detroit, in their best years would appear to have their playoff hopes get dashed in December.

It seems that Stafford having difficulty in December is not exclusive to Detroit.  Christmas weekend of 2021 with the Rams he threw several interceptions, as he did today, Jan. 02, 2022.

Is Stafford the best example of a quarterback who has the highest ratio of (INT on or after Dec. 1st)/(INT before Dec. 1st)?